# Why is the realized p/l still zero in my Interactive Brokers demo account?

Tags: stocks, online-trading, interactive-brokers, paper-trading

(I'm a beginner)
Why is the realized p/l still zero in my Interactive Brokers demo account? Is that because it is paper trading?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you closed any of your positions?

Comment: In order to have a realized P&L you would have had to have closed some positions.  Did you?

Comment: no, but I sell to open (option) and I didn't close it untill it expired but isn't the premium considered realized ?

Comment: @Hart CO   @ Bob Baerker

Comment: @huab No, the premium isn't considered realized. It's not realized until you close your position by buying back the option (or when it expires). It's like a "cost basis" but in the opposite direction.

Comment: @D Stanley It expired a week ago, so it should've been realized, right?